# Суммирование всех элементов с помощью GPU

Tags: c++, cuda

Здравствуйте! Не давно познакомился с CUDA, пишу маленькую программу для сравнения скорости на GPU и CPU. Ядро должно суммировать все элементы, но суммирует только последний элемент. В чем проблема? Может синхронизация нужна?

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
__global__ void add(int *matr, int N, int *sum)
{
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    //if (idx<N) sum+= a[idx];
    if (idx<N) *sum += matr[idx];
}


int main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int *matr_d;
    int *matr_h;
    const int N = 10;
    int *sum_d = 0;
    int *sum_h = 0;

    matr_h = (int*)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&matr_d, N * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        cout << (matr_h[i] = rand() % 10) << " ";
    cout << endl;

    cudaMalloc(&sum_d, sizeof(int));
    sum_h = new int[1];
    sum_h[0] = 0;

    cudaMemcpy(matr_d, matr_h, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(sum_d, sum_h, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    // int block_size = 4;
    // int n_blocks = N / block_size + 1;
    add << <1, 10 >> > (matr_d, N, sum_d);

    cudaMemcpy(sum_h, sum_d, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cout << "sum: " << sum_h[0] << endl;

    free(matr_h);
    cudaFree(matr_d);
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Проблема в том, что у вас код `if (idx<N) *sum += matr[idx];` выполняется для каждого элемента массива matr, в итоге в sum пишутся значения для каждого idx, а вам везет что в нем оказывается значение для последнего элемента.

Comment: Не посоветуете выход из этой ситуации?

Comment: @Romeon0 в свое время видел в учебных материалах NVIDIA нужный код, поищите.

Comment: @Romeon0 Презентация на английском, где разбирается задача суммирования: http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1.1-Beta/x86_website/projects/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf *(перенес из ответа Roman Fursenko)*

Answer (score 0):

@Владимир Мартьянов прав. Во первых, для решения задачи внешними источниками, нужны версии `CUDA`, `SM`, `COMPUTE`.
Есть простой до безобразия способ. Создайте символ `__shared__`, и атомарно аккумулируйте значение. Потом просто с хоста мапте значение `MapToSymbol`. Но тогда бессмысленно параллелить вычисления.
Второй способ, более сложный и требует понимания архитектуры CUDA. Смысл описан  [здесь: CUDA :: Memory Fence Functions](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#memory-fence-functions).